# In Reactjs on Windows suddenly the Mouse stopped working

Tags: reactjs

When I start the run debug of my app in Visual Studio Code(F5) then the mouse is not working. I can not anymore left click with the mouse but I can move the mouse pointer but no click is registered. I can press the keyboard "tab" and press ENTER but that's it. I can't see where to start debug this problem so I add my package.json maybe it can give some clue

In Windows I use the Chrome Browser and other apps and the mouse is behaving normally there.

What I did prior to this strange happening was that I tried the `"react-scripts": "5xx"`. And then I Went back to  `"react-scripts": "4.0.3"`

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "greta-thunberg-fff",
  "version": "1.2.9",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://greta.portplays.com",
  "main": "index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.2",
    "@types/recompose": "^0.30.9",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "clean-tag": "^3.1.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "comma-separated-values": "^3.6.4",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "firebase": "^7.23.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.5",
    "framer-motion": "^2.9.5",
    "gsap": "^3.5.1",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "mammoth": "^1.4.11",
    "material-table": "^1.69.2",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "normalize-wheel": "^1.0.1",
    "notistack": "^3.0.0-alpha.1",
    "npm": "^7.11.2",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^1.8.357",
    "preval.macro": "^5.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-activity": "^1.2.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-data-grid": "^6.1.0",
    "react-detect-offline": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.4",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-resize-detector": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.3",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3",
    "react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "^1.0.6",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "rebass": "^4.0.7",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.41.1",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.5",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "three": "^0.85.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.10.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=6545&& react-scripts start",
    "build": "§",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "clean-tag": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.2",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "rebass": "^4.0.7",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: When you open the inspector, you see a script/iframe blocking the content of your page ?

Comment: @Monstar Not sure I understand what you say. here's a [screenshot](https://snipboard.io/NeW8C6.jpg) . I still learn React

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this issue with `react-script` myself, and it seems to be a well-known issue.

As suggested in this [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11880#issuecomment-1005409614), you can do the following:

- Change the react-script version to 4.0.3 in `package.json`
- Add `"resolutions": { "react-error-overlay": "6.0.11" }` (latest version of [react-error-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-overlay)) to your `package.json`
- npm install react-error-overlay
- Delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
- Run `npm i`

Hope that fixes it.

Comment: I tried this exactly as you prescribe but nothing changes  looks like there's an IFrame yes blocking. Thanks I will read trough that GitHJub discussion

Comment: I would try with version 6.0.9 of react-error-overlay then by doing a ``npm i react-error-overlay@6.0.9`` and add that version in your ``package.json`` resolutions

Comment: Later if upgrading to react-script 5 maybe, should the react-error-overlay and resolution be removed?

Comment: I would keep it, it seems react-scripts v5 still has that issue